# Is there a Visual C++ plugin that works like codepad.org or similar services?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ide

I'd love to have a local C++ scratch pad without having to worry about creating projects, solutions, and files until I need that complexity for a particular test case. Interactive debugging on it would be the major advantage of using the IDE instead of a simple GCC/run script from an editor. Codepad and ideone don't allow system calls or filesystem operations, so that's a major drawback. A minor drawback to them is delay in compiling and limit on output, and of course, no chance of interactive debugging.

Comment: Why not just keep a scratch project somewhere and use that ?

Comment: There is some logic to what you say. I've had scratch projects before, but I always forget about them and use codepad instead. This seems like a personal problem...

Comment: It's just an organisational problem. FWIW I keep a `scratch` directory which has various scratch IDE projects, source files, makefiles, etc, which I use to try out ideas quickly. I never delete any of this stuff because sometimes it comes in useful again and I can just grep the scratch directory for whatever it is that I need to reuse.